# jupyter not found after pip install jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After many different ways of trying to install jupyter, it does not seem to install correctly.

May be MacOS related based on how many MacOS system python issues I've been having recently

`pip install jupyter --user`

Seems to install correctly

But then jupyter is not found

`where jupyter`
`jupyter not found`

Not found

Trying another install method found on SO

`pip install --upgrade notebook`

Seems to install correctly

jupyter is still not found

`where pip` `/usr/local/bin/pip`

What can I do to get the command line `jupyter notebook` command working as in the first step here: https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#running

Comment: how and where are you trying to call jupyter notebook ? If I remember right, you need to be inside the directory where you have your notebook to call it

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: Use `python -m notebook`

After updating to OS Catalina, I installed a brewed python: `brew install python`. 
 It symlinks the Python3, but not the `python` command, so I added to my `$PATH` variable the following:

```
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin
```

to make the brew python the default python command (don't use system python, and now python2.7 is deprecated). `python -m pip install jupyter` works, and I can find the jupyter files in `~/Library/Python/3.7/bin/`, but the tutorial command of `jupyter notebook` doesn't work. Instead I just run `python -m notebook`.

Comment: this worked! thank you. this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the local python install directory to your path. Apparently this is not done by default on MacOS.

Try:

```
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/<version number>/bin:$PATH"
```

and/or add it to your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

My MacOS has python 2.7, I installed python3 with **brew**, then the following commands work for me

```
brew install python3

brew link --overwrite python
```

```
pip3 install ipython

python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try solving this with [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) or Poetry.

[Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) makes it a lot easier to manage Python dependencies (including Jupyter) and build a virtual environment.

Here are the steps to adding Jupyter to a project:

- Run `poetry add pandas jupyter ipykernel` to add the dependency
- Run `poetry shell` to create a shell within the virtual environment
- Run `jupyter notebook` to to fire up a notebook with access to all the virtual environment dependencies

The other suggested solutions are just band-aids.  Conda / Poetry can give you a sustainable solution that's easy to maintain and will shield you from constant Python dependency hell.